# What does a number like this mean in Java: 0b1000_1100_1010? (The "b" between the numbers)

Tags: java, primitive-types

I'm practicing with some tasks of a Java course and I came across this variable

```
int x = 0b1000_1100_1010;
```

I know that a "f" and a "d" beside a number means that the number is a *float* or a *double*, respectively. But what about this "b" **between** the number?

I saw [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/underscores-literals.html) that this is related to *bytes*, but I didn't quite understand how it works.

My question also applies to the "x" between numbers that I just saw on that link.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the [binary literal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/binary-literals.html).

It's a notation to show that the number is represented in binary.

It's like when you use the hexadecimal notation: `0xF9`. In Java, you can use `0b1111_1001` to represent the same number, which is 249 in decimal.

It's not related to *bytes*, but to bits. You can clearly see which bits are set and which are not. By default a number starting with `0b` is an `int`, but you can write a long like this `0b1010L` (note the trailing `L`).

The `b` can be lowercase or uppercase. So this is also valid: `0B1111`. Note that since the `0b` prefix indicates a binary representation, you're not allowed to use any character other than `0` and `1` (and `_` to mark a separation).

Comment: Source: [JLS 3.10.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1): "A binary numeral consists of the leading ASCII characters 0b or 0B followed by one or more of the ASCII digits 0 or 1 interspersed with underscores". It's new in Java 7.

Answer (score 2):

Java allows you to use `_` in `int` values as shown below:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 1_2_3;
        System.out.println(x + 100);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
223
```

Comment: "But what about this "b" between the number?" How does this answer the question?

Comment: @AndyTurner - I missed `b` completely. I just saw it after your comment.

Answer (score -2):

> The byte data type is an 8-bit signed two's complement integer. It has a minimum value of -128 and a maximum value of 127 (inclusive).
>
> The byte data type can be useful for saving memory in large arrays,
>   where the memory savings actually matters. They can also be used in
>   place of int where their limits help to clarify your code; the fact
>   that a variable's range is limited can serve as a form of
>   documentation.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html